# Is it possible to inject with Dagger2 an object that was created using an Activity object?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

This is my MainViewModelModule class where I want to add the creation of MainActivity object:

```
public abstract class MainViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindMainViewModelFactory(MainViewModelFactory factory);

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel provideMainViewModel(MainViewModel viewModel);

    @Provides
    abstract MainActivity bindMainActivity(); //Create MainActivity object

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    static MyCustomClass provideMyCustomClass(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        return DataBindingUtil.setContentView(mainActivity, R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And this is how I tried to inject an MyCustomClass object into my activity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity {
    @Inject MainViewModel mainViewModel;
    @Inject MyCustomClass myCustomClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Use myCustomClass
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Android Studio is complaining with:

> error: @Binds methods must have exactly one parameter, whose type is assignable to the return type

Can anyone help me inject `MyCustomClass` object in `MainActivity`? Thanks

Comment: i'm going to try something, hopefully it works

Comment: @a_local_nobody Looking forward to see your answer. Thanks

Comment: try this and let me know, i'm not 100% sure it'll work, i think you need a provides and a bind

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks anyway. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Just did and I get this: `error: @Binds methods must be abstract`. So I cannot make abstract since I need an implementation for it.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Is it enough only to use this `abstract MainActivity bindMainActivity();` Is this line really creating an object of my activity class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198586/discussion-between-a-local-nobody-and-lilian-sorlanski).

Comment: I'm not sure what it is exactly that you're trying to do. First of all, you can't _create_ an Activity, because the Android system does that for you. Second, even if, you'd need a scope, or you'd keep creating new Activities. Third, it seems like this is within the `@Singleton` scope, which wouldn't be the correct scope for the Activity either, so the whole binding/creation would be in the wrong place. Lastly, if you're using Jetpack/Lifecycly ViewModels then you shouldn't create & inject them directly, or you would loose the one feature they're trying to add (keeping state on rotation)

Comment: @DavidMedenjak @DavidMedenjak "First of all, you can't create an Activity, because the Android system does that for you." This make a lot of sense. What I'm trying to do is very easy. I want to create an object of `MainActivity` that can be used in `provideMyCustomClass()` method to create an object of type `MyCustomClass`. This object I want to be injected in the activity. If this is not possible or it's wrong thinking, than please post an answer with that. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak This is the content of `provideMyCustomClass()` method `return DataBindingUtil.setContentView(mainActivity, R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Can you please provide a complete answer? Thank you.

Comment: Anything against using dagger's Android extension? I think it does exactly what you want .

Comment: @Fred What do you mean through "Dagger's Android extension"? Where can I find it and how can I use it? Thanks

Comment: It's all explained [here](https://dagger.dev/android)